"System problem detected" message multiple times on install or trial run via boot device
I am changing to a new-to-me DELL 3010 PC (i5/16Gb/2x240Gb).    The ISO file was downloaded a few days ago, more than once.  On booting from the USB flash drive, it starts off in the menus to choose language etc but soon presents and the error message.  If cancelled, it pops up frequently. Installing fails.
EDIT:   On retracing my steps, I chose an iso image from a different source.  The first one I tried was from the ubuntu.com download link   file ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso (6.1Gb),  retried with ubuntu.22.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso  (4.7Gb) from a list of different iso files, still on ubuntu.com.
When trying the install with this iso file, it ran as expected. I will retry with ubuntu 24.04...  and verify the iso file.
Thanks for your help.

You of course verified the ISO before making the install media. Also what version are you trying to install? Edit the question and add this info please.
